# Highcharts GANTT chart - need to allow category with no data

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to build a GANTT chart as in this JSFiddle example 
[ http://jsfiddle.net/2xkfm87e/11/ ] (I have now updated this fiddle to the working version using jlbriggs' input below. It also includes some other options I needed -i.e. tooltip on each interval.)

However, I need to display all the categories even if one or more do not have any associated data. The end user needs to be aware that there is no data associated with that category. In my JSFiddle example, the best I could come up with is just use the initial dates and create a point that informs the user that there is no data for that category. I would rather it be null.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

```
  $(function () {
        // Define tasks
        var tasks = [{
            name: 'Category 1',
            intervals: [{ // From-To pairs
                from: Date.UTC(2010,5, 21),
                to: Date.UTC(2015, 5, 21),
                label: 'Category 1'
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Category 2- Should be null',
            intervals: [{ // From-To pairs
                from: Date.UTC(2010,5, 21),
                to: Date.UTC(2010, 5, 21),
                label: 'Category 2- Should be null'
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Category 3',
            intervals: [{ // From-To pairs
                from: Date.UTC(2011,05,16),
                to: Date.UTC(2012,03,21 ),
                label: 'Category 3'
            }, {
                from: Date.UTC(2013,07,09),
                to: Date.UTC(2015,05,22),
                label: 'Category 3'
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Category 4',
            intervals: [{ // From-To pairs
                from: Date.UTC(2013,07,18 ),
                to: Date.UTC(2015,05,22),
                label: 'Category 4'
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Category 5',
            intervals: [{ // From-To pairs
                from: Date.UTC(2013,06,17),
                to: Date.UTC(2014,04,21),
                label: 'Category 5'
            }, {
                from: Date.UTC(2015,01,22),
                to: Date.UTC(2015,05,22),
                label: 'Category 5'
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Category 6',
            intervals: [{ // From-To pairs
                from: Date.UTC(2013,06,17),
                to: Date.UTC(2014,04,21),
                label: 'Category 6'
            }, {
                from: Date.UTC(2015,01,22),
                to: Date.UTC(2015,05,22),
                label: 'Category 6'
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Category 7',
            intervals: [{ // From-To pairs
                from: Date.UTC(2013,06,17),
                to: Date.UTC(2014,04,21),
                label: 'Category 7'
            }, {
                from: Date.UTC(2015,01,22),
                to: Date.UTC(2015,05,22),
                label: 'Category 7'
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Category 8',
            intervals: [{ // From-To pairs
                from: Date.UTC(2013,06,17),
                to: Date.UTC(2014,04,21),
                label: 'Category 8'
            }, {
                from: Date.UTC(2015,01,22),
                to: Date.UTC(2015,05,22),
                label: 'Category 8'
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Category 9',
            intervals: [{ // From-To pairs
                from: Date.UTC(2013,06,17),
                to: Date.UTC(2014,04,21),
                label: 'Category 9'
            }, {
                from: Date.UTC(2015,01,22),
                to: Date.UTC(2015,05,22),
                label: 'Category 9'
            }]
        }];

        // Define milestones
        /*var milestones = [{
            name: 'Get to bed',
            time: Date.UTC(0, 0, 0, 22),
            task: 1,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'triangle',
                lineWidth: 1,
                lineColor: 'black',
                radius: 8
            }
        }];
            */
        // re-structure the tasks into line seriesvar series = [];
        var series = [];
        $.each(tasks.reverse(), function(i, task) {
            var item = {
                name: task.name,
                data: []
            };
            $.each(task.intervals, function(j, interval) {
                item.data.push({
                    x: interval.from,
                    y: i,
                    label: interval.label,
                    from: interval.from,
                    to: interval.to
                }, {
                    x: interval.to,
                    y: i,
                    from: interval.from,
                    to: interval.to
                });

                // add a null value between intervals
                if (task.intervals[j + 1]) {
                    item.data.push(
                        [(interval.to + task.intervals[j + 1].from) / 2, null]
                    );
                }

            });

            series.push(item);
        });

        // restructure the milestones
        /*$.each(milestones, function(i, milestone) {
            var item = Highcharts.extend(milestone, {
                data: [[
                    milestone.time,
                    milestone.task
                ]],
                type: 'scatter'
            });
            series.push(item);
        });
            */

        // create the chart
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container'
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Category History'
            },

            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },

            yAxis: {

                categories: ['Category 9',
                             'Category 8',
                             'Category 7',
                             'Category 6',
                             'Category 5',
                             'Category 4',
                             'Category 3',
                             'Category 2',
                             'Category 1'],
                tickInterval: 1,            
                tickPixelInterval: 200,
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        color: '#525151',
                        font: '12px Helvetica',
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    },
                   /* formatter: function() {
                        if (tasks[this.value]) {
                            return tasks[this.value].name;
                        }
                    }*/
                },
                startOnTick: false,
                endOnTick: false,
                title: {
                    text: 'Criteria'
                },
                minPadding: 0.2,
                maxPadding: 0.2,
                   fontSize:'15px'

            },

            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ tasks[this.y].name + '</b><br/>' +
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%m-%d-%Y', this.point.options.from)  +
                        ' - ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%m-%d-%Y', this.point.options.to); 
                }
            },

            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    lineWidth: 10,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        align: 'left',
                        formatter: function() {
                            return this.point.options && this.point.options.label;
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            series: series

        });        
   });
```

Comment: Can't access your fiddle, because that is created with your fiddle account. So it is not piblic

Comment: Sorry about that, The link is fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highcharts default behavior will show the category even if there is no data, unless it is the first or last category.

You can just change your input array to have an empty `intervals` array in your case:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/2xkfm87e/1/

If you need the first or last category to be empty, you'll need to set the min and max on the Y axis:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/2xkfm87e/2/

Comment: @jlbriggs I came across this question and was wondering if it was possible to get multiple bar lines in one section.  Ex: Category 2 would have two lines, stacked vertically without touching.  Any ideas?

Comment: @NorCalKnockOut - you can fiddle with the x values, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3d3fuhbb/108/ use a decimal value below/above the category index for the series that need to share a category.

Comment: @NorCalKnockOut - but if you're looking to do a gantt chart with Highcharts, I would look here first: http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/804783-gantt-chart  Also, note that a "Gantt Chart Product" is on the roadmap (though without a timeline) - http://www.highcharts.com/support/roadmap

Comment: @jlbriggs Awesome! Thank you!