# I want to Jquery Libary for gantt Chart view month to month difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, gantt-chart

As per the client project scope i want to simple gantt chart or horizontal range bar graph for data and for that i have researched jquery library but i don't get any kind of library.

For more idea i have attached screenshot.

[Chart Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnmAu.jpg)

Comment: you can use highcharts. Here is the one your example can relate to. http://www.highcharts.com/demo/columnrange

Comment: I want date difference on **Y Axis** not on **X**

Comment: you can use [highchart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30487771/highcharts-gantt-chart-need-to-allow-category-with-no-data). here is the [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30487771/highcharts-gantt-chart-need-to-allow-category-with-no-data) for it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I am using [jquery.gantt](http://taitems.github.io/jQuery.Gantt/). It is easy to use, configure and integrate. You can download form [here(GitHub)](https://github.com/robicch/jQueryGantt). If you want to `gantt chart` by monthly view as par your screen shot. Just Configure as below.

```
scale: "months"
```

Example Image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think `d3.js` would be good to choose. This link might help:

```
http://bl.ocks.org/dk8996/5538271
```

Comment: Thanks but i am not able to customize as per the requirement.

Comment: Could you please explain in detail about the scenario what are you looking  in for?.. so that would better to suggest.

Comment: I have attached screenshot please check it

Answer (score 0):

You can get a zoomable timeline in the X axis as well as resizable appointments using the RadiantQ Gantt. Check this one close to what you need in the [online demo samples](http://demos.radiantq.com/jQueryGanttDemo/Demo.htm):
http://demos.radiantq.com/jQueryGanttDemo/Samples/FlexyGanttResourceView.htm

NOTE: I do work for RadiantQ.

Here is in fact a sample that we put together using our gantt that looks like yours:

[image]